# How to select keyboard in Tizen/HTML5 for Wearables

Tags: html, keyboard, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I have two system wide keyboards pre-installed on my Tizen Wearable device, the first one is a stock Samsumg's keyboard, the second one - Custom. The first one is a user's default selected in Settings.

I don't want to change the system's default, but I want my application to use the Custom keyboard.

In native API I've seen Tizen::Ui::InputConnection object that can be used as a property in Edit or TextArea controls, but I didn't see anything like this in HTML5 API. Searching Tizen's forum didn't help.

I've also seen in Tizen's SDK IME's WebHelperClient example a number of undocumented commands used to talk to a Tizen's service through a websocket. Probably there is a command to select an active keyboard, but I didn't find it.

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IMO that is not possible for either web apps or native apps.

Reason: 
1. In gear, simultaneously two Keyboard can't be active at the same time.

2. Also, suppose there is an API available which you can use to change to custom keyboard while your app is running, but what if you close your application not using the normal hardware exit(i.e. Swiping down), rather you close it from "Recent Applications" then the custom keyboard that you activated for your app will be set for other applications as well.

Also the documentation available here doesn't explain anything which you are asking
https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/guides/web-application/tizen-features/ime-application

Comment: That native InputConnection API makes me think that it's possible on Tizen, it's just not available in HTML API for wearables. The input method is associated with a particular UI control, not an app. When UI is gone, the keyboard is gone with it. In Android world there are many apps that use their own custom keyboard. Yes, documentation doesn’t explain anything and that's why I'm asking questions here :)